# How can I pause video of omxplayer using python script?

Tags: raspbian, python

I am using omxplayer to play videos. The video played very well. But I can't pause the video using the commands below. Can any one help me how to pause my video using python script?

Here, is the command I am using to pause my video ...

```
os.system('mkfifo t cat t | omxplayer --no-osd -b myvideo.mp4 &')

def play_pause():
    os.system('echo p > t rm t')
```

Comment: omxplayer can be controlled using dbus. There are python wrappers for this, e.g. https://pypi.org/project/omxplayer-wrapper/